# Mediawiki ToC (Table of contents not working)

Tags: mediawiki, tableofcontents

I feel like an idiot for asking this question, mainly because I've tried googling and reading the documentation, but I still don't understand why my mediawiki won't generate a table of contents for this page (entire code):

```
==First Section==

===First subsection of first section===

===Second subsection of first section===

==Second Section==

==Third Section==

==Fourth Section==

==Fifth Section==
```

I've tried adding **TOC** and **FORCETOC** but that hasn't helped. Any suggestions? (Humbly appreciative.)

Comment: Can you give us a link to your Mediawiki?

Comment: @klml Unfortunately I can't, the content on the wiki is private. But I may be able to provide other details if it helps.

Comment: Does it work for other pages in the same namespace? Is it not rendered, or rendered, but hidden by CSS? What extensions are activated? What MW version?

Comment: @leo It does not work on other pages. It is rendered, but hidden by CSS. Does that help? No extensions active, version 1.25.1 Thanks

Comment: @Dan What skin are you using? And do you have anything in your `MediaWiki:Common.css` that could cause it?

Comment: @leo Thanks so much, it was my MediaWiki:Common.css file. The toc tags had display:none.

Comment: Although this issues has been resolved (thanks to the help I received on here) I noticed that I have received several downvotes for this question. If the downvoters could explain, or someone else could explain, that would be appreciative.